# Something other than INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: inotifypropertychanged

I have the following property and pseudo-code method:

```
private DataModelMember _PropertyMember = new DataModelMember();
public DataModelMember PropertyMember
{
    get { return _PropertyMember; }
}

void GetWCFData()
{
    DataModel d = client.getWCFData();
    this._PropertyMember = d.result.anotherclass; //*(DataModelMember is anotherclass)
}
```

So, "this._PropertyMember = value" does in fact change the private member, it however does not update any of the properties inside (as evident with the databinding).  It almost seems like my 'DataModelMember' class needs to inherit some other interface to notify of the class copy?

Answer (score 0):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is not magic.
You need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event yourself whenever the property changes.